# How to rename a variable in selected lines in Visual Studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to rename a variable in selected lines in Visual Studio code. Not all occurrences of that variables.

I know `F2` can rename a variable, but it renames all occurrences of that variable.

I don't want to use find and replace, because it may replace some other text that looks the same but not that variable.

For example ::

```js
var i = 1;
function func1() {
  console.log("My value: " + i);
};
func1();
i = 10;
func1();

// rename all i below, NOT above
var i = 1;
function func1() {
  console.log("My value: " + i);
};
func1();
i = 10;
func1();
```

[image: Rename]

I need to rename the `i` in the selected lines. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press Ctrl+d, I regularly  use this on windows and linux so if your on macOs this might work differently I guess

Comment: It will take many `ctrl+d` for a very long code though. But I can't find a better solution so far.